# Lightning Calendar uses strange colors

Tags: calendar, thunderbird

I have installed Lightning Calendar in Thunderbird. I am using dark theme in Thunderbird, which Lightning takes over, except this little pop up calender, which is strange white background with white text (and thus unreadable). Is there any way to change the colors ?

Also, I would have liked having the days of the week (ie columns) marked with day name (ie, Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr, Sa, So). Is there any way to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if the colors, as displayed in your screenshot, come from your desktop environment, rather than Lightning Calendar itself.

I would suggest changing your desktop colors to see whether it has any effect on the displayed colors.

Comment: If this is the accepted answer, I suppose it worked for you.  I have the same problem, and I also have dark (background) colours in my system.  Do you remember which colours you had to change in your system settings to make this work?